# How to display a random resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a `Quote` model in my application. I have several quotes in the database. I want to display a random quote from Quote.all on my home page whenever the user refreshes it.

What do I need to put in the controller to be able to do this?

index.html.erb

```
<% for quote in @quotes %> ## this currently displays every quote in the databse
  <blockquote>
    "<%= "#{quote.body}" %>"
    <small><%= quote.author %></small>
  </blockquote>
```

Here's my quotes controller:

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /quotes
  # GET /quotes.json
  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /quotes/1
  # GET /quotes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /quotes/new
  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
  end

  # GET /quotes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /quotes
  # POST /quotes.json
  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.save
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @quote }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.update(quote_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /quotes/1
  # DELETE /quotes/1.json
  def destroy
    @quote.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to quotes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_quote
      @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:body, :author)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fetch a random `Quote` record and assign it to an instance variable you can then use in your views:

```
quote = Quote.first(offset: rand(Quote.count))
```

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: my snippet doesn't do any `each`. Try it out on a `rails console` - I've already tried the snippet before posting it

Comment: Yes, as manu29.d said, this picks *one* random `Quote` - you can't iterate over it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SQL random order

```
@quote = Quote.order("RAND()").first
```

Comment: This fails, at least in PG, with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  function rand() does not exist

Comment: Maybe you meant Quote.order('RANDOM()').first ?

Comment: Nope, it works in SQL.  I have no idea what the PG equivalent is, might be RANDOM() as you say

Comment: If you can keep it DB-agnostic it's better.  I prefer doing the random offset in the controller before passing it to ActiveRecord, like in @rkon's answer.

Comment: Btw the postgres random ordering isn't very nice - it requires you to supply a random number to select from, exactly like ruby's `rand(N)`:  `SELECT * FROM mytable OFFSET random()*N LIMIT 1;`.  So, if you want to randomly select from the whole table you also need to get the size of it: `SELECT myid FROM mytable OFFSET random()*(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable) LIMIT 1;` which is pretty clunky.  All the more reason to just do `:offset => rand(MyTable.count)` in rails.

Comment: Yes absolutely. MySQL treats RAND badly as well, performance-wise: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql

Comment: Fair enough, never seen rkon's way or considered it.  Always good to learn